# C/C++ preprocessor: how to generate code depending on number of arguments

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I want to be able to do this in my preprocessor macros

```
#define dble double
/* Just something that converts x to a double precision float. 
   static_cast used as an illustration: */
#define dble(x) static_cast<double>(x)
```

I know that overloading is not allowed by the C standard preprocessor. I also know that variadic arguments like

```
#define dble(...)
```

requires at least one argument, and omitting the parenthesis is not allowed. Even by the insight of that I cannot let go of the feeling that it must be a way to solve this problem. Do anyone have any smart ideas how it can be done?

Example of use:

```
dble x;
x = dble(3);
```

Background: *I am actually interested in using the C preprocessor for my Fortran code. I want to develop a simplified notation for variable declarations. DBLE would expand to DOUBLE PRECISION for standalone applications, or REAL(C_DOUBLE) if I am compiling for C-interoperability for a library with C interface. However, DBLE is a so called INTRINSIC in Fortran. DBLE(3) casts 3 to a double precision float. In standalone mode it would be 3.0d0. In C-interoperability mode it would be converted to 3.0_C_DOUBLE.*

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier just to `#define dbl double` or use some other abbreviation ?

Comment: Why not just have c_double everywhere? Or even better just some other integer constant you set at the top module, be it using preprocessor or not? Dble() as such is more or less deprecated.

Comment: Another option is to use conditional compilation of modules. Just create two modules with the same name and entities (containing e.g. the `KIND` of your types), then compile one of them depending on the case at end. Notice that, this solution just involves modifications to the build-system and does not require a pre-processor.

Comment: I agree that the DBLE intrinsic is deprecated. I would actually replace DBLE(x) with REAL(x,KIND=C_DOUBLE) in the case of C-interoperability.

maybe the best solution is to give up on DBLE as a variable type and use DOUBLE, DBL, REAL64 instead. But... I just want to make sure before I give up that there is no solution, at all, to my problem as stated above before. 

I am looking in /usr/include/tgmath.h right now. Lots of preprocessor tricks in here!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using static_cast - you're already in C++ world, wich allows you to use double(x). So defining dble double will work.

For more complex cases - well, cpp isn't designed to handle that. Maybe another preprocessor combined with regular expressions might help.

Comment: Sure that the C preprocessor is designed for more complex cases than that.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor can handle different number of arguments, but the implementation for such a thing is a bit tricky, especially for the case of distinguishing `0` and some arguments. In [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) I have macros for C99, if you are more interested in C++ (there is no such thing like C/C++, BTW) have a look into boost.

With P99 you could do something like this

```
#define dble(...) P99_IF_LT(P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), 1)(double)(static_cast_double(__VA_ARGS__))
```

where for C99 I would use a compound literal for the replacement of C++' `static_cast`

```
#define static_cast_double(X) ((double){ 0 } = (X))
```

but this would be a debade of its own rights.